# Constant prompts for FaceTime Password, iCloud Password and iMessage Password

Tags: icloud, messages, password, facetime

I don't use any of these services. Currently there is a dialog box permanently on the screen prompting for a password. If I press cancel, it's replaced instantly by another dialog box, prompting for a password for one of these services, apparently randomly chosen.

Sometimes, it's the same service several times in a row. Sometimes there is a pause of maybe half a second before the next dialog pops up.

Is this a known issue with Mavericks? It's a 2014 rMBP.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem on my i-phone 6, so  went into 'Settings' and turned 'Facetime' off!  I don't use Facetime, so it seemed the best way to get rid of the annoying pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Unknown password recovery work around for .pages document.
I found a way to recover contents.
Email the password locked pages document to yourself.
Open the received email. Open the attachment and you will find your content. Select all and paste into a new pages document.

Comment: This does not work. You will need to provide a more detailed example to prove that it does. It also does not address the OP question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).